# How to store RSSI Values in csv file on raspberry PI?

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, rssi

I am using Pi with builtin Bluetooth and wi-fi. How can I get continuously the RSSI values with the name of  of all the nearby Bluetooth Devices(Paired as well as without paired) and stored in a file?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at PyBluez: https://github.com/karulis/pybluez? I'm sure you can find what you need in regard to the Bluetooth component of your question in one of their examples.

In regard to writing a csv file, have a look at the documentation here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html